# what is different between matrix.size() == 0 and matrix[0].size() == 0

Tags: c++, vector

For a vector > matrix.,
what is different between matrix.size() == 0 and matrix[0].size() == 0?

```
 bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int> > &matrix, int target) {
    int n = matrix.size();
    if (n == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    int m = matrix[0].size();
    if (m == 0) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

matrix.size() returns how many **vector of int** in the matrix;
matrix[0].size() returns how many **int** in the vector matrix[0]

Answer (score 0):

`matrix` is a `vector<vector<int> >`, or a vector of vectors. If it is empty, there are no vectors inside it.

`matrix[0]` is a the first vector inside `matrix`. It is a `<vector<int>`. If exists, `matrix` is not truly empty, because it contains an element. But if it is empty, there is no useful data inside `matrix`.

Answer (score 0):

- **matrix.size()** = size of matrix vector
- **matrix[0].size()** = size of **first element** of matrix vector. Suppose matrix is empty, then this will give you a *segmentation fault* or *undefined behavior*.

This code simulates a matrix using a vector of vectors. They use both vectors for the number of columns and rows. It is possible to use vectors like that, but it isn't a very good idea IMO, because nothing prevents you from having vectors of different size inside. Imagine:

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix;
vector<int> row;
row.push_back(1);
matrix.push_back(row);
row.push_back(2);
row.push_back(3);
matrix.push_back(row);

cout << "matrix.size() = " << matrix.size() << endl;
cout << "matrix[0].size() = " << matrix[0].size() << endl;
cout << "matrix[1].size() = " << matrix[1].size() << endl;
cout << "matrix[2].size() = " << matrix[2].size() << endl;
```

This gives:

```
matrix.size() = 2
matrix[0].size() = 1
matrix[1].size() = 3
matrix[2].size() = 25802
```

Some remarks:

- as you can see; matrix contains **two** vector (since we used twice `matrix.push_back()`
- matrix[0] contains **one** element, since we only did once `row.push_back(1);` before putting this subvector in matrix.
- Nothing imposes matrix[0].size() and matrix[1].size() to have the same dimension
- accessing matrix[2].size() which was never filled gives *undefined behavior*